# Create index for sequential occurences in group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe in R, two groups might look like this:

```
id     tnr
1      1
1      1-3
1      4
1      5
1      6
1      6-8
1      8-9
1      10
1      10-11
1      12
2      1
2      2
2      3
2      3-4
```

The problem are the overlapping numbers. In a first step, I split the numbers at the `-` character in order to convert both parts to numeric. I then did some comparisons with `ifelse`-statements to identify the overlapping numbers, which gives me a dataframe like this:

```
id     tnr     ovlp
1      1       1
1      1-3     1
1      4       0
1      5       0
1      6       1
1      6-8     1
1      8-9     1
1      10      1
1      10-11   1
1      12      0
2      1       0
2      2       0
2      3       0
2      3-4     1
```

In a final step, I need to identify the the occurence of each subgroup within the group. The result should be something like this:

```
id     tnr     ovlp     occ
1      1       1        1
1      1-3     1        1
1      4       0        0
1      5       0        0
1      6       1        2
1      6-8     1        2
1      8-9     1        2
1      10      1        3
1      10-11   1        3
1      12      0        0
2      1       0        0
2      2       0        0
2      3       1        1
2      3-4     1        1
```

I first thought about numbering each sequence by using `0` as delimiter. This works for most instances, but sometimes, there is no `0` between two sequences. Like in the example, when I have overlapping numbers from 6-9 and then from 10-11 in the first group.
So, I guess I need to use my `ifelse`-statements somehow to paste this index to the `occ`-column, but I can't figure out, how. Any ideas? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: The code I use to identify the overlapping numbers:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(ovlp = ifelse(tnr_a == lag(tnr_a) & id == lag(id) |
                               is.na(tnr_b) == FALSE & tnr_b == lag(tnr_b) & id == lag(id) |
                               tnr_a == lag(tnr_b & is.na(tnr_b) == FALSE & is.na(lag(tnr_b)) == FALSE & id == lag(id) |
                               lag(tnr_a) == tnr_b & is.na(tnr_b) == FALSE & is.na(lag(tnr_b)) == FALSE & id == lag(id) |
                               tnr_b == lag(tnr_b) & is.na(tnr_b) == FALSE & is.na(lag(tnr_b)) == FALSE & id == lag(id) |
                               str_detect(tnr, "\\-") == TRUE & lag(tnr_a) > tnr_a & lag(tnr_a) < tnr_b |
                               lag(str_detect(tnr, "\\-")) == TRUE & lag(tnr_a_) < tnr_a & lag(tnr_a) > tnr_b, 
                             1, 0)) %>%
  relocate(ovlp, .after = tnr) %>% 
  mutate(ovlp = ifelse(lead(ovlp) == 1 & lead(id) == id, 1, tnr_gruppe))
```

Edit 2: The sample data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), tnr = c("1", "1-3", "4", "5", "6", "6-8", "8-9", 
"10", "10-11", "12", "1", "2", "3", "3-4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: Why is occ for 10 and 10-11 in the first id 3?

Comment: Could you place your data set (using dput() ) and your current code into your question as well? It'll make it much easier to help. And at first glance I would say that one approach may be to split your tnr column into two (min and max for each row). If the max of one row is smaller then the next row's min you have a new group.

Comment: @tmfmnk: because it's new subgroup. occ = 2 refers to the overlapping numbers from 6 to 9, occ = 3 to the overlapping numbers from 10 to 11.

Comment: @MarioNiepel: Unfortunately I can't share the dataset, as it is from a confidential source. I included the code I use to identify the overlapping numbers, though. `tnr_a` and `tnr_b` refer to the numeric parts of `tnr`. `tnr_b` is `NA`, when there is no second numeric part. I did the split a few steps earlier. However, I am still unable to figure out how to number these sequences within a my groups...

Comment: I’m not suggesting to share any more data than what you are already showing. You want people to be able to help you without requiring them to manually type in your data. If you share it via dput() it can just be copied and pasted to test code.

Comment: @MarioNiepel: Ah, this was a misunderstanding, my appologies. I added the sample data above, thanks for pointing me to the dput()-function. I am still pretty new to R and stackoverflow. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option involving `dplyr` and `tidyr` might be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 separate_rows(tnr) %>%
 group_by(id, tnr) %>%
 mutate(ovlp = as.integer(n() > 1)) %>%
 group_by(id) %>%
 mutate(occ = with(rle(ovlp), rep(cumsum(values) * values, lengths))) %>%
 group_by(rowid) %>%
 summarise(across(-tnr, first),
           across(tnr, ~ paste(., collapse = "-"))) 

   rowid    id  ovlp   occ tnr  
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>
 1     1     1     1     1 1    
 2     2     1     1     1 1-3  
 3     3     1     0     0 4    
 4     4     1     0     0 5    
 5     5     1     1     2 6    
 6     6     1     1     2 6-8  
 7     7     1     1     2 8-9  
 8     8     1     1     3 10   
 9     9     1     1     3 10-11
10    10     1     0     0 12   
11    11     2     0     0 1    
12    12     2     0     0 2    
13    13     2     1     1 3    
14    14     2     1     1 3-4
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm with my sample data. I tried to apply this to my dataset, but encountered some problems. The criteria for finding the overlaps are a bit more complicated and the seperator ist not always a "-". But your code gave me some examples going in the right direction.